# SVG: grouping paths with outline border (and creating a new path based on the existing ones)

Tags: svg, path, outline

I got a SVG-file with four paths (four squares) in it:

```
<html>
<body>

<svg height="1000" width="1000">
    <path fill="blue" id="square1" d="M0 0 L0 100 L100 100 L100 0 Z" />
    <path fill="green" id="square2" d="M100 0 L100 100 L200 100 L200 0 Z" />

    <path fill="yellow" id="square3" d="M0 100 L0 200 L100 200 L100 100 Z" />
    <path fill="red" id="square4" d="M100 100 L200 100 L200 200 L100 200 Z" />
</svg>

</html>
</body>
```

[four squares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHWpt.png)

I would like to divide these four squares visually into two groups (blue/green & yellow/red).

A frame should be drawn around the two blue squares as well as around the two green squares.

How can I add an outline-border line around these two groups of squares?

Would it also be possible to automatically create a new object for each group that has its own ID?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use a smaller square on top of a bigger square to make borders e.g.:

```
<path fill="black" id="square1-bg" d="M0 0 L0 100 L100 100 L100 0 Z" />
<path fill="blue" id="square1" d="M3 3 L3 97 L97 97 L97 3 Z" />
```

As far as templating JS might be the best bet:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lyzpe35m/10

Comment: The real case is a bit more complicated: there are about 400 polygons, which I would like to divide into four groups. so i'm looking for a way to group the polygons and add an outside border line for each group.